# VS-Code: Search for files containing two strings

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code, file-search

I would like to use the file search in VSCode to filter for all files which contain two different strings - like "https" and "json_encode". 
The Regex search of VSCode looks promising - but it seams to be limited "per line".

I tried:

```
https(.*)json_encode
```

Comment: `.` doesn't match new line (not sure about VSCode), `[\s\S]` does

Comment: No, `[\s\S\r]*` will.

Comment: @yacc haha, @Wiktor,Stribiżew isn't `[\s]` equivalent to `[\r\n\t\f\v ]` and already contains `\r`?

Comment: @AshishRanjan In "regular" regular expressions, yes. In the patterns VSCode and Visual Studio use, no.

Comment: Thanks - seems to be a duplicate. Thanks for the answer anyway. Maybe my title helps to find the answer, so I will keep the question in SO.